# worpress custom taxonomy title display also shows description

Tags: php, wordpress, tinymce, wordpress-theming

In my theme it gets the title of the custom taxonomy here

```
<div class="<?php echo $filters_id . ' '; echo $filters_width;  if($layout == 'constrained_fullwidth') echo ' fullwidth-constrained '; if($span_num != 'elastic-portfolio-item' || $layout == 'constrained_fullwidth') echo 'non-fw'; ?>" data-alignment="<?php echo $filter_alignment; ?>" data-color-scheme="<?php echo strtolower($filter_color); ?>">
            <div class="container">
                <?php if($filter_alignment != 'center' && $filter_alignment != 'left') { ?> <span id="current-category"><?php echo __('All', NECTAR_THEME_NAME); ?></span> <?php } ?> <
                <ul>
                   <?php if($filter_alignment != 'center' && $filter_alignment != 'left') { ?> <li id="sort-label"><?php echo (!empty($options['portfolio-sortable-text'])) ? $options['portfolio-sortable-text'] : __('Sort Portfolio',NECTAR_THEME_NAME); ?>:</li> <?php } ?>
                   <li><a href="#" data-filter="*"><?php echo __('All', NECTAR_THEME_NAME); ?></a></li>
                   <?php wp_list_categories(array('title_li' => '', 'taxonomy' => 'project-type', 'show_option_none'   => '', 'walker' => new Walker_Portfolio_Filter())); ?>
                </ul>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

however whilst it displays the title great, if I add a description, the plugin also displays this here too

I want to make it only show the title...

I am using Salient Visual Composer plugin and showing the Projects "widget" in my page

The page in questions is http://www.jonnyrossmusic.com/acts-2/ where if you click Acoustic for example it also shows the description

I am assuming the problem lies at `<?php echo __('All', NECTAR_THEME_NAME); ?>`

Thanks